# After install Docker CE on 20.03, network interfaces disappear

Tags: networking, wireless, configuration, docker

Before I followed the Docker instructions for installing Docker CE on Ubuntu 20.04 (actually xubuntu), my system had an on-board Ethernet controller connected to a 10.1.1.x network (internal network) and a USB WiFi that was connected to a 192.168.4.x network that connected to my home router. After I installed Docker CE, when I do "ip a", I only see the loopback device (lo) and the docker interface (docker0 with an address of 172.17.0.1).

I can still find both controllers. Here is the output for lspci:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 148f:5372 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Both are supported by the kernel since they previously worked with no proprietary drivers.

I've dome some searching but I didn't find anything that helped. I tried walking through the "Wireless network trouble shooter" guide and it didn't help (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html.en)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your `lsusb` output wasn't from `lsusb`, it was a second copy of your `lspci` information, so I removed it as it wasn't the output you indicated.